# event listeners compounding after each page refresh

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, event-listener, clicklistener

So I used this tutorial to build a custom right click menu for some graphs: https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

It's working great, but I have one problem with the listeners. Specifically, when contextListeners and clickListeners functions are called, event listeners are added *when the page loads*. However, in my application, I have a button which redraws these graphs and reloads the page that the custom right click menu is attached to, and every time, new listeners are created. As a result, the function associated with the right click menu is called twice if I load two different graphs, and thrice if I load it three times. Here's the function that keeps getting called, and keeps adding listeners

```
function contextListener() {
                        document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
                            taskItemInContext = clickInsideElement(e, taskItemClassName);
                            if (taskItemInContext) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                toggleMenuOn();
                                positionMenu(e);
                            } else {
                                taskItemInContext = null;
                                toggleMenuOff();
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

and in a later function I tried:

```
document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
                            console.log("removed");
                        });
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: where exactly is contextListener() getting triggered?

Comment: they're triggered all at the beginning in an init function when i call them.

Comment: Is the init function in a document.ready call?

Comment: if your contexListener() is triggered in your init, which is triggered in your document.ready(), then that's your issue. every time your page reloads, document.addEventListener is called, adding another listener each time.

Answer (score 1):

i don`t understand you question well ,but you can try this :

```
function contextListener() {
                if(!document.handAddcontext){
                    document.handAddcontext = true
                    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
                        taskItemInContext = clickInsideElement(e, taskItemClassName);
                        if (taskItemInContext) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            toggleMenuOn();
                            positionMenu(e);
                        } else {
                            taskItemInContext = null;
                            toggleMenuOff();
                        }
                    });
                }

                }
```